# How to add functionality in Calculator app flutter

Tags: javascript, java, flutter, kotlin, dart

I have been building a flutter calculator app for the first time in terms of functionality but stuck in between here is the code below

```
import 'package:calculator/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Calculator',
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
            // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
            // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      String output = '0';
    
      /* String _privateOutput = "0"; */
      /* double num1 = 0.0;
      double num2 = 0.0;
      String task = ""; */
    
      Widget calculatorButton(String numberText) {
        return Expanded(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                numberText = output;
              });
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Text(
              numberText,
              style: kCalculatorStyle,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget calculatorButtonSymbols(String text) {
        return Expanded(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: kCalculatorStyleSymbols,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget calculatorButtonTopSymbols(String text) {
        return Expanded(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: kCalculatorStyleSymbols1,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget calculatorResetButton() {
        return Expanded(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.refresh,
              size: 30,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.white10,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          ),
        );
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SafeArea(
                  child: Text(
                    output,
                    style: kCalculatorStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: Divider()),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        calculatorButtonTopSymbols('AC'),
                        calculatorButtonTopSymbols('+/-'),
                        calculatorButtonTopSymbols('%'),
                        calculatorButtonSymbols('/'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        calculatorButton('7'),
                        calculatorButton('8'),
                        calculatorButton('9'),
                        calculatorButtonSymbols('x'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        calculatorButton('4'),
                        calculatorButton('5'),
                        calculatorButton('6'),
                        calculatorButtonSymbols('-'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        calculatorButton('1'),
                        calculatorButton('2'),
                        calculatorButton('3'),
                        calculatorButtonSymbols('+'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        calculatorResetButton(),
                        calculatorButton('0'),
                        calculatorButton('.'),
                        calculatorButtonSymbols('='),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Could someone please help me? I want to know how to update the numbers on the Screen "OUTPUT" when I press the number keys

Please help me I really want to learn flutter!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `calculatorButton` is inverted :

```
          setState(() {
            output += numberText;
          });
```

In this way you'll concat the `numberText` to the `output`.

Comment: Thank you very much bro that worked appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. try this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calculator',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String output = '0';

  /* String _privateOutput = "0"; */
  /* double num1 = 0.0;
  double num2 = 0.0;
  String task = ""; */

  Widget calculatorButton(String numberText) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            output= numberText;
          });
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Text(
          numberText,
         
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget calculatorButtonSymbols(String text) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Text(
          text,
          
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget calculatorButtonTopSymbols(String text) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Text(
          text,
         
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget calculatorResetButton() {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.refresh,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: Text(
                output,
                
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Divider()),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    calculatorButtonTopSymbols('AC'),
                    calculatorButtonTopSymbols('+/-'),
                    calculatorButtonTopSymbols('%'),
                    calculatorButtonSymbols('/'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    calculatorButton('7'),
                    calculatorButton('8'),
                    calculatorButton('9'),
                    calculatorButtonSymbols('x'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    calculatorButton('4'),
                    calculatorButton('5'),
                    calculatorButton('6'),
                    calculatorButtonSymbols('-'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    calculatorButton('1'),
                    calculatorButton('2'),
                    calculatorButton('3'),
                    calculatorButtonSymbols('+'),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    calculatorResetButton(),
                    calculatorButton('0'),
                    calculatorButton('.'),
                    calculatorButtonSymbols('='),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You were wrong in setState() it should be like this, **output** is the state we update **numberText** is a parameter

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
     output= numberText;
  });
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your response honestly appreciate it! it worked as well learned something new! Please keep helping like that.... :-)

Comment: Cool   If my answer is useful please mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, you had the assignment the wrong way around, here is the correct version:

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
     output= numberText;
  });
},
```

However, you need to think about how best to handle different logic for different button text. Here is the start of an approach where you pass a callback function to each button:

```
  void digitPressed(String digit) {
    String newOutput;
    if (digit != '.') {
      if (output == '0') {
        newOutput = digit;
      } else {
        newOutput = output + digit;
      }
    } else if (!output.contains('.')) {
      newOutput = output + digit;
    }

    setState(() {
      output = newOutput;
    });
  }
```

Then all the numeric buttons call this callback:

```
  Widget calculatorButton(String numberText, Function digitPressed) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          digitPressed(numberText);
        },
```

They are created with the callback:

```
            Row(
              children: [
                calculatorButton('7', digitPressed),
                calculatorButton('8', digitPressed),
                calculatorButton('9', digitPressed),
                calculatorButtonSymbols('x'),
              ],
            ),
```

So far we have the same general purpose callback for each button. The other buttons will need different callback functions, of course.

In order to implement operators you will need to remember the previous output from before the operator. If you are going to implement operator precedence then you would need a stack of values. I am sure you can google for calculator algorithms, good luck!

Comment: I forgot to say you could move the `calculatorButtonXxxx` widgets out of the parent widget, and make them `StatelessWidget`s with a `const` constructor, and use the keyword `const` when creating them. Then these widgets would not rebuild when the parent widget rebuilds on state changes, giving better performance.

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment - the widgets cannot have a `const` constructor because of the `Function` callback.